# Does order matter when using "ON" in joins sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005

when writing a query using any joins does it matter which side the On is based

Example

```
select * from customer C
join Address ON A.CustomerId=C.CustomerID  -- would it make a difference if I did    ON    C.CustomerId=A.CustomerID 
where c.CustomerId=1
```

What about left or right joins?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You are still joining the two tables.  I would consider it best practice to put the joining table on the right handside.

Comment: ok.Good to know,was not sure if the order after the "ON" mattered.

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter?  No.

LEFT vs RIGHT - depends on the results you want.

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.aid=b.aid
```

will give you all results from A whether or not they have a matching record in B - so the fields returned from B will be NULL for records where B doesn't match.

```
SELECT * FROM A RIGHT JOIN B ON ...
```

will give you all records from B and the possibility of null values in the fields provided by A...

Answer (score 0):

Equality is a commutative operation. `A=B` is the same as `B=A`, so the specific ordering in the JOIN clause is irrelevant.

If you were doing inequality tests, `<` and `>`, then the ordering would matter. `B>A` is not the same `A>B` (and ditto for `A<B` and `B<A`)